# jQuery UI Tabs: Ajax within Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am attempting to rewrite a multi-page website into a SPA using jQuery UI Tabs. In the shell page, one tab references an id within the page, while the rest of the tabs load other pages via AJAX. It looks something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/learn.html">LEARN</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/listen.html">LISTEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/support.html">SUPPORT</a></li>
        <!--etc.-->
    </ul>
    <div id="home">
        <!--blah blah blah-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Within `learn.html`, I have another set of UI tabs that are set up the same way:

```
<div id="tabs2">
    <ul id="nav2">
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/sponsors.html">Sponsors & Donors</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/staff.html">Staff & Board</a></li>
        <!--etc.-->
    </ul>
    <div id="about">
        <!--blah blah blah-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem arises in clicking a tab within `learn.html`: the event of clicking one of the AJAX tabs within this AJAX tab bubbles up to the window, and `sponsors.html` or whatever loads in place of the shell page.

I have tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it did not work; using `event.preventDefault` on the tabs prevented the tab functionality in the first place. What else is there to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the result of the ajax call to a specific div. In the success function of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling preventDefault on the click of the tab, or the anchor? You might need to setup a separate handler for the anchor click.

```
$("ul#nav2 li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I was calling preventDefault on the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is gone now...

The page I had loading via AJAX had its own doctype and head tag and the whole shebang. After I removed that, I no longer had any problems.